# How to remove first element from every sub-array in 2-Dimentional class numpy.ndarray in Python

Tags: numpy

I have a `numpy.ndarray` like this -

`[[1,2,3],[-7,7,2],[2,-3,4]]`

I want remove the first element of each array and convert it into

`[[2,3],[7,2],[-3,4]]`

Is there any function that can do this, rather than having to use an explcit `for` loop?

Comment: `np.array([[1,2,3],[-7,7,2],[2,-3,4]])[:,1:]`?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much Abdou for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved using `list comprehensions` as well -

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[-7,7,2],[2,-3,4]]

my_list_out = [i[1:] for i in my_list]
print(my_list_out)
     [[2, 3], [7, 2], [-3, 4]]
```